# Mozilla Firefox @font face doesn´t work

Tags: html, css, firefox

In my Style.css is the following code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'newbold'; 
src: url('../fonts/newbol-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compatibility Modes */
src: url('../fonts/newbol-webfont.ttf');
src: url('../fonts/newbol-webfont.woff');
}
```

Thats just relative paths no absolute and firefox doesn´t want load the fonts...
The .htaccess solution doesn´t solve my problem..

Comment: What .htaccess solution? What is the specific problem? Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" Was the solution that i found in the web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure why you don't just put this in your CSS:

```
* {
 font-family: newbold, sans-serif;
}
```

This code works fine for me when I tested it.

Comment: #text {
 font-family: "newbold" sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 40px;

} doesnt word

Comment: That would work, but it would be easier to use body { or * { rather than #text.

Comment: Thank you. I use the * selector and use in the textboxes different fonts